# Faster approach to spark wholeTextFiles for multiple unformatted files. PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm using spark to read multiple little files. Each file is a client specific format and contains multiple tables (each with a different structure). We have created a python parser which works and handles partitioning given the path. Let me explain via schema:

```
folder
|- file_number=0001
   |- year=2019
      |- month=10
         |- day=21
            |- hour=17
               |- file.txt
|- file_number=0002
   |- year=2019
      |- month=10
         |- day=21
            |- hour=17
               |- file.txt
etc
.
.
.
```

So the naive approach is:

```
sc.wholeTextFiles('/path/to/file_number=*/year=*/month=*/day=*/hour=*/*.txt')\ # This is a pair (path, file Content)
  .flatMap(lambda x: parser(x[1], x[0]))\ # This is the parser function. Is plain python and works fast. We use the path to pick up the partitioning. The parser returns a list of tuples that's why flatMap
  .foldByKey([], lambda x, y: x + y)      # The key is the table name and the value is the data as a list of dicts in a tabular-like style
```

The transformation `.wholeTextFiles('/path/to/file_number=*/year=*/month=*/day=*/hour=*/*.txt')` takes an insane amount of time, considerig than the rest takes not so much.

Up to [this](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/480/how-do-i-ingest-a-large-number-of-files-from-s3-my.html) blog, the problem might be some recursive call, so it is much better to list all files first and then read each file. I haven't be able to use Hadoop's `FileSystem.open(path)` as propose in the link because I am working on Azure Data Lake Gen2. But it is true that listing all files using `dbutlis.fs` is fast.

So the question is: ***How can I use such a list to read and parse files in parallel?***. The problem is that `wholeTextFile` does not accept a list as an argument. I have try all of the following:

```
list_of_all_files_paths = dbutils.someCode()

# Attempt 1: Type mismatch
rdd = sc.wholeTextFile(list_of_all_files_paths)

# Attempt 2: Works but all partitiong info is lost
rdd = spark.read.text(list_of_all_files_paths, wholetext=True)

# Attempt 3:  Takes a lot of time too
rdd = spark.read.text('path/to/')

# Attempt 3: This is the most succesfull approach... but looks sooo bad, and is not very fast neither...
rdd = sc.emptyRDD()
for path in list_of_all_files_paths:
  newRDD = sc.wholeTextFiles(path)
  rdd    = rdd.union(newRDD)
```

Comment: can you convert list into string using wholeTextFiles: `rdd = sc.wholeTextFile(','.join(list_of_all_files_paths))`

Comment: that's why I asked `can you`, if you don't like it, just skip it.

Comment: @jxc I do like it!!. Actually it is a good solution. Maybe I've express myself wrong. I was meaning "Oh my god, I've been fighting aginst this problem some many hours and it is soo simple solution I cannot believe"

Comment: that's good. I don't want to go for an answer when it's too short. just feel free to add as your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jxc have answered in the comments. The solution is very simple:

```
rdd = sc.wholeTextFile(','.join(list_of_all_files_paths))
```

Turns out that string representing a list of paths is a valid input. The times are still high due to the amount of `I/O` but at least the listing part has become very small